# Construct an expression that bounds the truncation error for a given value of x.

Tags: numerical-methods

The function that has been approximated with a Taylor Series is:

$$f(x) =  \frac{log(x) - x + 1}{(x-1)^2} $$

It resulted in:
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} (x-1)^{k-2}$$

I know truncation error is:

$E = f(x) - T_n (x)$

From this, I want to construct an expression that bounds the truncation error, assuming n > 2, for a given value of x.

How does one do this with a Taylor series approximation? Do you use Taylor remainders?

Comment: There is simply not enough information here to determine what your question is about. You need to add more details.

Comment: I have added more information, thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a geometric series as majorant,
$$
|f(x)-T_m(x)|\le\frac1{m+1}\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty |x-1|^{n-2}=\frac1{m+1}\frac{|x-1|^{m+1}}{1-|x-1|}.
$$